# Images in Woocommerce are not alligned properly?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have issue on my [Woocommerce site](https://5thfashion.com/product-categorie/kleding/page/2/). Main image on some products are not alligned properly making mess with title. See problem bellow:

[image]

I tryed old method to set images width and height , and after that regenerate thumbnails, but seems do not work in Woocommerce 3.3.X. Can someone to tell me how to fix this, or give me some instructions how to?

This is CSS i think that control that part..

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin: 0 0 1em;
box-shadow: none
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting different heights which is causing some items to align incorrectly.

```
.product_cat-tops .et_shop_image {
    height: 360px !important; }

.product_cat-jurken .et_shop_image {
    height: 320px; }
```

You have lots of different heights in your CSS set: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwmjseaj/

If you set both of these to the same height, the captions will line up nicely :-)

Comment: I inserted css, but dont see changes... still the same. Also issue is not only on tops category. Have more categories like that.

Comment: @Rob I have only highlighted the error. You will need to set all the heights the same to get them to line up.

Comment: I set now all to the same height but still looks bad. Can you help me?

Comment: Updated all. check now

Comment: Change all of them to `360px`, including the ones at the bottom of the stylesheet.

Comment: If i do that, on mobile view are causing title overlaping with image.. https://5thfashion.com/product-categorie/kleding/page/2/  See image: https://i.imgur.com/o3DhmOD.png?1

Comment: You'll have to change the height using media queries to make the style of the item better on mobile.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/